# Inline assembly in kernel module

Tags: kernel, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

The inline assembly in my kernel module code is following:

```
   u64 cade_seg;
   __asm__ __volatile__ ("mov %%cs %0": "=r" (code_seg));
```

However, when it compiles (as kernel module), error is thrown that "junk `rax` after register." Is there anything wrong with the inline assembly code above.?

Update: by replacing `%%cs` with other register, say `%%rax`, the error persists.

Comment: If you use intel syntax, and not AT&T, the cs register should be the second argument of the mov instruction

Comment: that is not the reason... (after swap still the same type of error)

Answer (score 1):

In assembly language, the registers should be separated by a comma:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("mov %%cs, %0": "=r" (code_seg));
```

Also segment selectors are a 16 bit type.